# Utility to simulate simple http responses

Tags: http, response, simulation, utility

I'm doing quite a lot of work with a javascript messaging system at the moment and end up making lots of use of netcat scripts to monitor and simulate as yet unimplemented server responses.

Does anyone know of a utility that can easily manage this sort of thing for prototyping purposes other than setting up a full webserver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Node.JS](http://nodejs.org/#about) (depends on [V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/)).

Comment: That's great thanks, I was having a play with cherrypy but this is much more consistent.